# Is there a python equivalent for .isConnected functionality in C#

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I have been looking for the equivalent of [isConnected() functionality] of C# in PYTHON. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connected?view=net-5.0

What I basically need is to check if the socket connection is still open on another end (primary server). If not, move the connection to a new socket(backup server).

I have been quite blank as to how I can move the existing connection to another server without having to reconnect again. Any kind of guidance and help will be really appreciated.

Right now, my connection to server is done at Login(). I want that just in case primary disconnects, the existing username moves to secondary. He just should perform file and word operations. What changes should I do in my code to achieve this.

My current code structure is:
Client side:

```
 def file_operation():
      do_something

 def word_addition():
      do_something

 def login():
      s.connect(host,port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Server side:

```
  def accept_client():
      s.accept
      do_something

  def GUI():
     accept_client()

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: And what information are trying to get with that? That the has been good earlier?

Comment: Even in C# `.isConnected()` doesn't really do much. In particular, despite its name, it cannot really tell you if you still have a connection.

Comment: @KlausD.  My requirement is: I need to see if primary socket is connected.. If it is not, then move the existing client connection to backup server...

Comment: @gunr2171  the functionality used in link is for C#. I need this same functionality in Python

Comment: You can see if a socket is not connected, but you can not reliability see if it is connected. Just send whatever has to be send and handle exceptions if they are raised.

Comment: @KlausD. how can i possibly see if socket is not connected? that can server my purpose. I feel try except is just a workaround but not a good solution

Comment: Why is that not a good solution?  Exception handling is used all the time to solve problems like this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey because in my existing functionality, this code is already being run in the exception block. So I do not want to execute another try except in that block. It will become like exception overloading(not a formal term). I am not sure if that is a good practice

Comment: You should only need one `try` block.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-exception-handling-in-python/#highlighter_938154:~:text=Code%20%232

Comment: @RobertHarvey let me give this a try. if this works out, will definitely update you here.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python Sockets documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), no, there isn't.  Python sockets are merely a wrapper around the Berkeley Sockets API, so whatever is in that API, that's what's in the Python API.

If you look at [the source code for Microsoft's Socket.cs class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs), you'll see that they maintain a [boolean flag field `m_IsConnected`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,287a0c1505e4afe6) to indicate the socket's current connection status.  You could potentially do the same with your own custom sockets class, using Microsoft's code as a model for writing your Python code.

Or, you could simply use the socket as you normally would, and switch to a different server when a socket error occurs.

Comment: Yes i need to move my existing connection information to different server. This is what I am trying to achieve. But I am not getting the approach as to how I can move in that direction.   If you know how I can move my existing connection information to different server without having to reconnect, could you please shed some light on it

Comment: `how I can move my existing connection information to different server without having to reconnect` -- You can't.  Sockets don't work that way.  You have to disconnect from the original server and make a new connection to the new server.

Comment: Right now, my client is making use of a username to connect with the server. The server maintains that information. Suddenly primary crashes and secondary has to take up responsibilities of primary. Now I want the user does not to enter the username again. just starts performing his activities. How can I achieve this?

Comment: By saving the user name in the client so that the user doesn't have to enter it again?

Comment: I have made the changes in my ques to better clarify what i want. Also, by saving you mean that I hard-code the username? Also, even if I maintain a list of username at client side, how will this help backup server to maintain the connection information. How will server know that what clients are already connected?

Comment: The backup server already knows about the new connection you make to it.  I'm just following your trail of bread crumbs; you said "I can't disconnect and reconnect because I don't know the user name."  I said, "Then store the user name in a variable in the client when you get it from the user."  I never mentioned anything about hard-coding.

Comment: If you need something more robust than this, have a look at a message broker like [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: Yes, if it is a new connection, the backup server knows about it and can do everything. But if it is an old connection, the backup server does not know what to do as per my above functionality(because connection is being made in Login() at the client side). What needs to be there in backup and client that existing ones get stored there.

Comment: In existing functionality, port is opened in the login(). So when a new connection comes, it goes in Login(), then to other functions and it works fine. But if existing connection is moved, it should not go to Login(), instead to either File_operation() or word_addition().

Comment: Then I suppose you have two choices: force a new login if you lose the existing connection, or make your File_operation and word_addition methods capable of establishing a new connection to a new server if you lose the existing connection.

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to achieve, but not really getting how to do. I do not really see much information on Google as well for this. This is the reason I thought, to check if socket is connected in file_operation or word_addition. If it is connected, just start performing whatever you want to do. Otherwise make a connection and then do what you want to do

Comment: So since you don't have an `IsConnected` option, what you'll have to do is trap the socket error, connect to the new server, and retry your operation.